# How to mark a type as not null?

Tags: kotlin, nullable, non-nullable

I want a generic method (or class) to behave something like this:

```kotlin
val instanceS = MyCoolClass<String?>()
instanceS.someMethod("some not null string") //compiles
instanceS.someMethod(null) //doesn´t compile
val instanceS2 = MyCoolClass<String>()
//Exactly the same
instanceS2.someMethod("some not null string") //compiles
instanceS2.someMethod(null) //doesn´t compile
```

Just as I can mark a generic type (that can already be nullable) to be nullable like this:

```kotlin
fun <T> doSomething():T? = ...
```

Isn't there something to mark a type (that can already be non nullable) to be non nullable??

```kotlin
fun <T> doSomething():T! = ... //this is not valid syntax
```

Comment: I do have control over MyCoolClass, but not over T, and T can be nullable

Comment: So you're saying you want to define a function that can declare to the compiler that it returns a non-null value, even if the input T was a nullable type?

Comment: Exactly that. Seems like a difficult endeavor. I've achieved something similar in a method, using a second type parameter, and adding a `where R:T, R:Any`, but not in a class, and the second type parameter it's really undesirable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A definitely not-null type is denoted by using `T & Any`. This type is the non-nullable version of `T` if `T` happens to represent a nullable type.

```
fun <T> doSomething(someInput: T, someNonNullDefault: T & Any): T & Any {
    return someInput ?: someNonNullDefault
}
```

This example could of course be achieved like this:

```
fun <T: Any> doSomething(someInput: T?, someNonNullDefault: T): T {
    return someInput ?: someNonNullDefault
}
```

but if `<T>` is scoped to the class rather than the function like in your sample code of what you want, then this feature has a lot more usefulness.

This feature requires Kotlin 1.7.0 or higher.

Comment: Which I'm using! you're a scholar, thanks a lot. Tried, and working! Didn't know Kotlin already had intersection types! This changes everything