# How can I restrict generic parameter to be non-nullable?

Tags: kotlin, generics, kotlin-extension, non-nullable

I have following signature:

```
 fun <T, R> JsonNullable<T>.map(func: (T) -> R): JsonNullable<R> {
```

How can I restrict T and R to be non-nullable ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75684939/how-to-mark-a-type-as-not-null

Comment: Importantly, the _second_ part of the answer to the linked duplicate is what you need: just write `<T : Any, R : Any>`.

Comment: @Louis Wasserman but if I want to apply non-nullable for return type I can use:
```
 fun <T, R> JsonNullable<T>.map(func: (T) -> R): JsonNullable<R & Any> {
```
?

Comment: Do you actually want `R` to be able to be nullable, or do you just want the return type to be the "non-nullable version of R"?

Comment: @Louis Wasserman I want to have R nullable but returnType must contain non-nullable version of R

Comment: Yes, then the code in your above comment is the way to do it.